# Django Gcloud from windows

Tags: django, windows, gunicorn

I am working on a Django App, using Windows.

Whenever I try to deploy to GCloud, I get exec: gunicorn error.

I know Gunicorn does not work on Win, but my understanding was that having it installed and running locally was not necessary to deploy, just putting into requirements.txt (where it is).

I could not find any answer online.

Can I deploy to GCloud using Gunicorn from Windows, or it must be done from Unix environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to deploy to GCloud ? With a Docker and Cloud Run or App Engine ?

Comment: Hi. With App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

With AppEngine on GCloud, you do not need to have gunicorn.
Check the example given by Google : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python3/django

Here is the `requirements.txt` :
`Django==3.2.5 django-environ==0.4.5 psycopg2-binary==2.9.1 google-cloud-secret-manager==2.5.0`